# How to pass custom datatype while calling MPI_Bcast?

Tags: fortran, mpi, precision

I am using 'custom' precision defined as `integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15,307)`. Then `Real(dp)` is used to declare the buffer.

Using `call MPI_Bcast(buffername,int count,dp,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)` gives me error `Invalid datatype` for dp.

Is there a way to pass this custom-defined datatype?

Comment: Are you using the phrase *custom data type* precisely? If you are, show us the statements you use to define and to commit it.

Comment: Do you need to create a data type? https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v3.1/man3/MPI_Type_create_f90_integer.3.php

Comment: I think there is a confusion between kind numbers and MPI datatypes here. They are very different. As Mark mentions, an MPI datatype must be created and commited separately.

Comment: https://theartofhpc.com/pcse/mpi-data.html#Fortran90kind-definedtypes

Comment: It looks like you just need to (perhaps manually) define the corresponding MPI datatype for your double precision real. Are you really encountering systems where `DP` is not the same as `MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION`?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, and links. I was using the terms incorrectly, indeed! All I needed was to call `MPI_Type_create_f90_real`. Also, thanks @Ross for pointing out that I can just use `MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION` for this case.

Comment: Systems where MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION would be a larger type can quite reasonably exist. The cleanest complement for that one is `dp = kind(1.d0)`